# React-router match params and forward button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following bit of code using react-router.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { categories, isFetching, filterCategories, match } = this.props
    if (categories.length === 0 && !isFetching) {
        this.props.fetchData("categories", requestCategories, receiveCategories)
    }        

    window.onpopstate = ()=> {            
        filterCategories(match.params.category || "")
    }
}
```

**Expectation** 
match.params.category will always return the category as per what is in the URL

**What actually happens**
this works fine normally but when i press the forward button, the match.params.category returns the value of the previous URL.
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug?

Comment: Use `exact` keyword in your router

Comment: can you show your router code, where you have declered

Comment: @SangramBadi the router code is here:[link](https://github.com/thierryMic/redeable/blob/master/frontend/src/components/App.js). I should probably mention that I use history.push in my category component when the use click on a button.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by using `matchPath` and 'location.history'.
This allowed me to get around the fact that `match`appears to have an incorrect url when the back or forward buttons are pressed.

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router'
class CategoryContainer extends Component {


getCategoryFromUrl = (url) => {
    const match = matchPath(url, {path: '/:category', exact: true, strict: false})
    return match === null ? "" : match.params.category
}

/**
* @description - trigger a request action
*/
componentDidMount() {
    const { categories, isFetching, filterCategories, match, history } = this.props
    if (categories.length === 0 && !isFetching) {
        this.props.fetchData("categories", requestCategories, receiveCategories)
    }

    filterCategories(match.params.category || "")

    window.onpopstate = () => {
        filterCategories(this.getCategoryFromUrl(history.location.pathname))
        }

}
```